# Rademacher complexity definition

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I am learning the Rademacher complexity and have a question on the definition of it.
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hypothesis class and $m$ is the number of iid samples from a distribution $\mathcal{D}$, say, $S=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Then the Rademacher complexity is defined to be
$$
R_s(\mathcal{H}) := \mathbb{E}_{\sigma} \sup_{h \in \mathcal{H}} \frac{1}{m}\left|\sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i \ell(h,x_i) \right|,
$$
where $\sigma_i$'s are iid uniform on $\{-1, 1\}$.
It seems that the more appropreate definition should be 
$$
\tilde{R}_s(\mathcal{H}) := \mathbb{E}_{\sigma} \sup_{h \in \mathcal{H}}\left| \frac{1}{|S_+|}\sum_{i \in S_+} \ell(h,x_i) - \frac{1}{|S_-|}\sum_{i \in S_-} \ell(h,x_i)\right|,
$$
where $S_+ = \{i \in [m] | \sigma_i = 1\}$ and $S_+ = \{i \in [m] | \sigma_i = -1\}$.
This is because the cross-validation should take the normalization constants into account. But I am not sure why the definition does not reflect the normalization constants.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Rademacher complexity is not directly related to the cross-validation . If you want an intuitive explanation for RC think of it as the degree in which a family of functions can fit purely random noise .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure why we want to fit purely random noise and why it is related to the genearlization. I thought we are looking for a quantity which can measure the genearlization.

Comment: We don't want to fit random noise . The idea is that if we look at two families of functions , the one that can fit better random noise is richer , "more complex" . Think about two extremities : first a hypothesis class with only one function and second the set of all functions defined on the domain with values in $\{,1\}. The first class has $R_{S} = 0$ and the second 1 (assume a suitable loss function) , .The first is as simple as we can get and the second is the most complex possible .

Comment: RC is mearly a convenient theoretical measure of complexity that can be computed or estimated for important sets of functions . Regarding the generalisation , as with any other measure of complexity, a lower RC is better .